# TypeError: unorderable types: dict() < dict()

Tags: python, dictionary

I am totally new to python and i got a script that produces this error

```
for a in sorted([p for p in PRODUCERS.Get('PartitionName="{}"'.format(partition)) 
                 if p["SignalName"] not in EXCLUDED_SIGNALS]):
```

> ```
> TypeError: unorderable types: dict() < dict()
> ```

The script was made with python 2.7 and i am using 3.5(32 bit).Is there something that changed?

Here is the function:

```
def tests_init(partition, dll, fce_name, limit_skip, limit_show, outputs):

all_inputs = {}
all_outputs = {}

# prepare inputs and outputs
for a in sorted([p for p in PRODUCERS.Get('PartitionName="{}"'.format(partition)) if p["SignalName"] not in EXCLUDED_SIGNALS]):
    all_inputs["{}__{}".format(a["ProducerFunction"],a["SignalName"])] = a["SignalType"]
for a in sorted([c for c in CONSUMERS.Get('PartitionName="{}"'.format(partition)) if c["SignalName"] not in EXCLUDED_SIGNALS]):
    all_outputs["{}__{}".format(a["ConsumerFunction"],a["SignalName"])] = a["SignalType"]

all_outputs["InvalidRdResult"] = "uint32"
all_outputs["InvalidRd4Result"] = "uint32"
all_outputs["InvalidWrResult"] = "uint32"
all_outputs["InvalidWr4Result"] = "uint32"

# init test
order_dict, help_out = test_init(all_inputs, all_outputs, partition, outputs, limit_skip, limit_show)

all_outputs = {o:all_outputs[o] for o in all_outputs if o in help_out}

file_desc =  "Testing Ports initialization and functions"
file_desc += "\n;                    portDclrRd()/portDclrRd4()/portDclrWr()/portDclrWr4()"
file_desc += "\n;                    for invalid signal name input"
file_desc += "\n;                    Initial values for port signals are defined in Input Tables"
file_desc += "\n;                    in related SRDD/DRD sections where the signals are produced."
if(partition=="fcm"):
    file_desc += "\n;                    This file contains {} half of output signals".format({0:"first", 1:"second"}[int(limit_skip/limit_show)])
    file_desc += "\n;                    Files are divided due to line length limitations in CTP tool"
```

Comment: The error says it all, `p` is a dictionary and you cannot use them as elements of the list you want to sort

Comment: Well, you're trying to sort a list of dicts. Python doesn't know how to compare two dicts for "smaller than-ness".

Comment: Your list comprehensions are creating lists whose elements are `p` and then again with `c`, but those are dictionaries.  So you have a list of dictionaries (dicts).  You then pass them to `sorted` to sort them, but in order to do that, it has to know how to order the individual dictionaries.  It's telling you that it can't do that, since dictionaries are unordered.  So you can get rid of the calls to `sorted`, or change your lists not to contain dicts.

Comment: @TomKarzes how can i change my list in order not to contain dicts?

Comment: @Tom The problem is not that dicts are unordered. You can't sort *a dict*. You *can* sort *a list of dicts*. If Python knew how to tell which dict is "greater", that is.

Comment: @Alex That depends on what you need your result to be. If you need your result to be a list of dicts, rather think about how that could possibly be sorted.

Comment: @deceze When I said that dicts are unordered, I meant that a dict is unordered with respect to another dict.  I was not talking about item order within a dict.  E.g., you get an error if you try to do `{1:2} < {3:4}`  I should have said that dictionaries are unordered with respect to other dictionaries.

Comment: @Tom OK. The word "unordered" already has a meaning with dicts, so that term was ambiguous. "Unorderable" is more apropos I think.

Comment: @deceze Yes, taken out of context what I said was clearly wrong, although what I meant wasn't.  The point is, you can't sort a list of dicts.

Comment: @AlexKolydas In answer to your question, `PRODUCERS.Get()` (and presumably `CONSUMERS.Get()` ) returns a dict.  You're saving those dicts in a list.  You can probably just remove the call to `sorted()`.

Comment: You _can_ sort a list of dictionaries if you pass `sorted()` a `key` function the compares two `dicts`. No one can write that for you since you have described what in them and how that determines their order.

Comment: @martineau Yes, good point.  I should have mentioned that as another alternative.

Answer (score 2):

An example of sorting list of dicts:

In the example the key is the 'id' field. You need to decide what is the proper field to use.

```
lst = [{'name':'jack','id':12},{'name':'sam','id':4},{'name':'ben','id':152}]
print(sorted(lst,key = lambda i: i['id']))
```

output

```
[{'name': 'sam', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'jack', 'id': 12}, {'name': 'ben', 'id': 152}]
```

Comment: What if I don't care what the order is, I just need it to be consistent? E.g. for unit testing purposes? It would be handy to be able to order any list of objects consistently.